Website not loading API requests on Iphone connected to the local host on computer via hotspot
I have a basic frontend, which sends a API request to the backend and gets a json response. Very basic web application.
I want to try it on my phone and I found this link which guided me on how to do that.
How can I access my localhost from my Android device?
The problem now is, the HTML webpage/Frontend does not load the API requests, however when I go the the server from my phone I can still see the api requests going through.
Since I am doing this on my phone I cannot see the developer tools but I am 100% sure the problem isnt in my code since it works fine in getting the requests on my computer and getting the request from the server on my phone.
Anyways here is my code for the frontend
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Auction Sprint</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadData()">
  <header>
    <div style="overflow: auto;">
      <h1>Auction Sprint     <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"></h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Auctions</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Sign In/Login</a>
    
  </nav>
  <div class="container" id ="itemsContainer" >
    <div class="auction-item">    
      <h2>The Death of Marat by Jacques-Louis David (Reproduction)<img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/21/7921-050-1607C28F/Death-of-Marat-Jacques-Louis-David-Royal-Museums-1793.jpg" class="preview"></h2>
      <p>Category: Art</p>
      <p>Seller: ArtReproductionCollector456</p>
      <p>Description: Selling a reproduction of The Death of Marat by Jacques-Louis David. It's in reproduction condition. Bought it at an art fair, but need to downsize.</p>
      <p>Current Bid: $500</p>
      <p>Last 3 Bids: $450, $480, $490, </p>
      <p>Bidding ends in: 2023-12-02T23:59:59.000Z</p>
      
      <button class="bid-button">Bid Now</button>
      </div>
    <!-- Add more auction items here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

header {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.auction-item {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: left;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;

}

.auction-item:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.auction-item h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.auction-item p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bid-button {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.bid-button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 47px;
}

.preview {
    max-width: 200px;
    float: right;
}

JavaScript
async function loadData() {
    try {
        res = await fetch("http://localhost:4545/items")
        data = await res.json()
        if (!res.ok) {
            console.log("problem")
            return 0
        }
        data.forEach(element => {

            itemsContainer = document.getElementById("itemsContainer")
            itemDiv = document.createElement("DIV")
            itemDiv.className = "auction-item"
            previousBids = element.previousBids
            previousBidsText = ""
            for (i = 0; i < previousBids.length; i++) {
                previousBidsText += `$${previousBids[i]}, `
            }

            itemDiv.innerHTML = `    
        <h2>${element.name}<img src="${element.image}" class = "preview"></h2>
        <p>Category: ${element.category}</p>
        <p>Seller: ${element.seller}</p>
        <p>Description: ${element.description}</p>
        <p>Current Bid: $${element.highestBid}</p>
        <p>Last 3 Bids: ${previousBidsText}</p>
        <p>Bidding ends in: ${element.endTime}</p>
        
        <button class="bid-button">Bid Now</button>
        `
            itemsContainer.appendChild(itemDiv)


        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

    }
}


and here is my code for the backend
//import Express.JS
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//Import Mongoose for MongoDB
const mongoose =  require("mongoose")
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://stuffffff")

//Import itemModel.js
require("./itemModel")

//Import the model from itemModel.js 
const Item_Model = mongoose.model("items_collection")

//Import Body Parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Import Cross Origin Resource Sharing.
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions ={
    origin:'*', 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200,
 }
 
 app.use(cors(corsOptions))

//create host
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("This is our main end point")
})


//open express server
app.listen(4545, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected")
})




//Create an Item
app.post("/item", async (req, res)=>{
    let newItem = {
        "name"          :   req['body']['name'], 
        "image"         :   req['body']['image'],
        "description"   :   req['body']['description'],
        "category"      :   req['body']['category'], 
        "seller"        :   req['body']['seller'], 
        "highestBid"    :   req['body']['highestBid'],
        "previousBids"  :   req['body']['previousBids'],
        "endTime"       :   req['body']['endTime']

    }
    let item = new Item_Model(newItem)
    try{
        await item.save()
        console.log("new item Created")
    }catch(error){
        throw err
    }

    res.send("successfully created new item ")
})


//Read All Items
app.get("/items", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        items = await Item_Model.find()
        res.json(items)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})


//Read 1 Item
/*
app.get("/item/:id",(req,res)=>{
    Item_Model.findById(req.params.id).then((item)=>{
        res.json(item)
    }).catch(err =>{
        if(err){
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html")
        }
    })
})
*/
app.get("/item/:id", async (req, res) => { //< Marks the callback as async
    try{
        const item = await Item_Model.findById(req.params.id);      //< Use of await keyword
        if(!item){                                                  //< item will be null if no matches in database
            return res.status(400).sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html")  //invalid id //return res.status(400).json({message: 'No Item found'})
        }     
        return res.status(200).json({
            item: item
        });
    } catch(err){
        //console.log(err); //< Log the actual error so you can check
        return res.status(500).sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html"); //invalid id less than 26 char
        // i want to send a message to html error page and redirect them to it 
    }
});


//Delete an Item
app.delete("/item/:id", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        item  = await Item_Model.findOneAndDelete({"_id":req.params.id})
        console.log(item)
        res.send("Item Successfully Removed")
    }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
    }
})


//Redirect If page Doesn't exist
app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/404.html")
            })   


@JaromandaX my computer is running both the backend server and the frontend server, I can access both from my phone but on my phone the frontend server does not load the data from the api, however when i go to the 4545 port aka my backend server on my phone I can see the api request is runnning

@JaromandaX no everything is running on my computer, i am simply just trying to access it from my phone

in what way are you using your phone? opening that web page served by your computer? which includes the code await fetch("http://localhost:4545/items")

@JaromandaX I open ip_of_my_computer:5500/Frontend, 5500 is the port the frontend is running on and /Frontend is the directory i have the html file in.
When i go to ip_of_my_computer:4545/items I see the api request has been sent

your javascript code, however, fetches from http://localhost:4545/items ... if your web page is open in your phone, localhost IS THE PHONE (I removed the other 2 times I pointed this out, as it seems to confuse you)

ahhhh i understand now, so what should I change the localhost part to not be hardcoded in?, is there a way to make it programically detected?

All I can say is "something that works" - having absolutely no idea of any details of your setup, that's the best I can do

I changed it to the ip of my computer and it works on both now Thank you so much
